# Display Wordpress Custom Post Type Taxonomies

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I am using Advanced Custom Fields in wordpress and have created 2 taxonomies for the Custom Post type - Attorney. The Taxonomies are *Practice Areas* and *Admitted to Practice*. I also have a template created to display the information for each attorney called single-attorneys.php

I am using the code:

`< ? php the_taxonomies('practice_areas'); ? >`

But I want to display each Taxonomy in a seperate line not all together like you see [here](http://glankler.biz/attorneys/jeremy-g-alpert/) in the *Admitted to Practice* area

What am I missing?

Comment: Ok so I am using: 

<?php the_taxonomies( $post->id, 'practice_areas', 'Practice Areas:', ', ', '') ?> - 

See page: http://glankler.biz/attorneys/jeremy-g-alpert/ and scroll to the bottom - 

which is working. I would like to remove the first Practice area and the and between them. I would like to add a break between all listed taxonomies. Is this possible? Thanks again for all the help this code is a little beyond my experience.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need like this:

```
<?php get_the_term_list( $post->id, 'practice_areas', 'Practice Areas:', ', ', '') ?>
```

and

```
<?php get_the_term_list( $post->id, 'admitted_to_practice', 'Admitted to Practice:', ', ', '') ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may adjust the output format of the_taxonomies by "before" or "after" argument

```
<? php the_taxonomies( "after=<br>" ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The template tag "the_taxonomies" takes 5 parameters

1.Post
 2.before
 3.sep
 4.after
 5.template

Think you have passed the wrong parameter(the taxonomy itself ).

Echos "get_the_taxonomies" after parsing the args and joining seperator

To get rid of taxonomy Name , just edit the template param from the default '%s: %l.' to '% %l' . As that is parsed through wp_sprintf , a wrapper for sprintf the 'and' will still be there .  There is a filter to wp_sprintf_l to change this and the code will look like this.

```
function remove_and( $separators ) {
    $separators[ 'between_last_two' ] = ' ';
    return $separators;
}
add_filter( 'wp_sprintf_l', 'remove_and' );
```

Think you should better use "get_the_term_list " where you can style it as you wish.

Comment: Ok so I am using: <?php the_taxonomies( $post->id, 'practice_areas', 'Practice Areas:', ', ', '') ?> - which is working.

I would like to remove the first Practice area and I would like to add a break between all listed taxonomies. Is this possible? Thanks again for all the help this code is a little beyond my experience.

Comment: To get rid of taxonomy Name , just edit the template param from the default '%s: %l.' to '% %l' . As that is parsed through wp_sprintf , a wrapper for sprintf the 'and' will still be there . Think you should better use "get_the_term_list " where you can style it as you wish.

Comment: <?php get_the_term_list( $post->id, 'practice_areas', 'Practice Areas:', ', ', '') ?> Doesn't seem to work - It doesn't return anything.

Comment: Please try ` $id = 'post_id' ;$taxo = 'taxonomyname';  echo get_the_term_list($id,$taxo,'<ul><li>','</li><li>',</li></ul>'); ` will give the unordered list of terms in 'taxonomyname'